# Cannot start JBoss 7.1.0 Final

Tags: eclipse, jboss, jboss7.x

I am new to JBoss. I installed JBoss 7.1.0 Final on Eclipse Luna. And when I start the server it gives me error. Tried to find it over internet, but no luck.

Error :

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoadException: Error loading module from E:\Java\jboss\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\modules\org\jboss\as\standalone\main\module.xml
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleXml(ModuleXmlParser.java:249)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleXml(ModuleXmlParser.java:200)
    at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleLoader.parseModuleInfoFile(LocalModuleLoader.java:147)
    at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleLoader.findModule(LocalModuleLoader.java:124)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModuleLocal(ModuleLoader.java:245)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.preloadModule(ModuleLoader.java:194)
    at org.jboss.modules.LocalModuleLoader.preloadModule(LocalModuleLoader.java:97)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:176)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:172)
    at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:311)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[25,69]
Message: Unexpected content of type 'element start' named '{urn:jboss:module:1.1}module'
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleXmlParser.unexpectedContent(ModuleXmlParser.java:312)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleXmlParser.parseDocument(ModuleXmlParser.java:503)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleXmlParser.parseModuleXml(ModuleXmlParser.java:244)
    ... 9 more
```

Help!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you use [jboss tools](http://tools.jboss.org/)? Eclipse doesn't support current JBoss out of the box.

Comment: No, I dont you use jboss tools

Comment: Can you go to the folder `E:\Java\jboss\jboss-as-7.1.0.Final\bin`, open a terminal window (cmd prompt in Windows) and run `standalone.sh` (Linux) or `standalone.bat` (Windows) and update your question with what happens?

Comment: Also, I'm unsure why you're using an old version of JBoss, but I assume it's because you're new to it. JBoss AS (the unsupported edition of JBoss EAP) changed its name to WildFly. It kept the same version numbers, so the latest WildFly is version 8.2; 9.0 should be out very soon. The reason they changed the name was just to avoid confusion when everyone just said "JBoss" and no-one knew if they meant the free, unsupported version, or the supported enterprise version.